# How to view the full shell error from a vim script?

Tags: vimscript, shell, plugin-fzf, fzf

I have been using vim/nvim for years on my desktop, and one of the most useful libs I have is the [FZF vim plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim), specifically the command that lists the tags from the current buffer:

> :BTags [QUERY]:   Tags in the current buffer

While this command works just fine on my desktop, It returns this error on my termux terminal on my android:

> Failed to extract tags

## What I have tried

I know that my `<project_root>/tags` file is all good (because when I run the command

> :Tags [QUERY]:    Tags in the project (ctags -R)
> it works perfectly:

[image]

I went through the plugin code to search for the above error message, and found [this](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/master/autoload/fzf/vim.vim#L830):

```
" ------------------------------------------------------------------
" BTags
" ------------------------------------------------------------------
function! s:btags_source(tag_cmds)
  if !filereadable(expand('%'))
    throw 'Save the file first'
  endif

  for cmd in a:tag_cmds
    let lines = split(system(cmd), "\n")
    if !v:shell_error && len(lines)
      break
    endif
  endfor
  if v:shell_error
    throw get(lines, 0, 'Failed to extract tags') <---------- error here
  elseif empty(lines)
    throw 'No tags found'
  endif
  return map(s:align_lists(map(lines, 'split(v:val, "\t")')), 'join(v:val, "\t")')
endfunction
```

I looked up what `shell_error` is, and got [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#v:shell_error):

> v:shell_error Result of the last shell command.  When non-zero, the last
> shell command had an error.  When zero, there was no problem.
> This only works when the shell returns the error code to Vim.
> The value -1 is often used when the command could not be
> executed.  Read-only.
> Example:

## Question

the error is too generic for debugging. How can I get the actual shell error that's happening?

## Update

based on the comments I added

```
echom cmd 
echom lines
```

in the `if v:shell_error` condition, and I got this

```
ctags -f - --sort=yes --excmd=number 'app/Repositories/Orders/AppOrdersRepo.php' 2> /dev/null | sort -s -k 5                                                          
[]
Failed to extract tags    
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The thing is if I copy that exact same command and run it on the termux shell, I get the exact same output as I do on my desktop version like so:

```
ctags -f - --sort=yes --excmd=number 'app/Repositories/Orders/AppOrdersRepo.php' 2> /dev/null | sort -s -k 5

App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders  app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      3;"     n
checkout        app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      69;"    f       class:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders\\CheckoutController
repository      app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      23;"    v       class:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders\\CheckoutController
CheckoutController      app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      21;"    c       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders
OrdersTypeConstants     app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      5;"     a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Contracts\\OrdersTypeConstants
StoreOrderPreferencesConstants  app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      11;"    a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Contracts\\StoreOrderPreferencesConstants
UserConstants   app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      12;"    a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Contracts\\UserConstants
OrdersRepoFactory       app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      6;"     a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Factories\\OrdersRepoFactory
Controller      app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      10;"    a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller
Order   app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      8;"     a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Order
CurrencyReplacementRepo app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      13;"    a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:App\\Repositories\\CurrencyReplacementRepo
Auth    app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      7;"     a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:Auth
Request app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      9;"     a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:Illuminate\\Http\\Request
Statsd  app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php      14;"    a       namespace:App\\Http\\Controllers\\Orders        typeref:unknown:Statsd
```

yet the command crashes in the fzf/vim.vim.. very strange.

Comment: One idea is to find the commands themselves and run them, or possibly try `:debug`

Comment: Yeah debug just gives the exact same error

Comment: Maybe you could edit the plugin's code and in the `if v:shell_error` condition add a `echom cmd` and `echom lines` this way you should be able to see the actual command and its results (or to get them back with `:messages`)? It's hacky but that should work.

Comment: @statox I did as instructed, got this
`ctags -f - --sort=yes --excmd=number 'app/Http/Controllers/Orders/CheckoutController.php' 2> /dev/null | sort -s -k 5                                                                                                     []                                                                                                           Failed to extract tags`

Comment: I followed up on this with a question on [FZF's GitHub page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/1390)

Comment: Could also be a shell issue. Try: `:set verbose=5`. Vim should output now the shell command which is going to call. Check, if this whole command works from a terminal